# toggle display of p tag depending on the value inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im assuming this shouldn't be too difficult to solve, but i'm pretty much a novice when it comes to Javascript or JQuery.

HTML:

```
<p><span id="AddLine1Summary"></span>,</p>
<p><span id="AddLine2Summary"></span>,</p>
<p><span id="TownCitySummary"></span>,</p>
<p><span id="CountySummary"></span>,</p>
<p><span id="PostcodeSummary"></span></p>
```

When the customer does not fill in the Address Line 2, there is still a value of `","` present so in the summary page it looks like this :

```
12 Bob Street,
,
BOLTON,
Lancashire,
BL1 1AC
```

So Im trying to get rid of the whole line `<p><span id="AddLine2Summary"></span>,</p>` when the customer leaves this blank. So far I have tried and come to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

if ($('#AddLine2Summary:contains(",")').length == 1) {
    $("#AddLine2Summary").parent().hide();
}

});
</script>
```

`parent.hide` because I have to hide the whole `<p>` not just the `<span>`

Comment: A duplicate of [non display of p tag depending on the value inside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957070/non-display-of-p-tag-depending-on-the-value-inside). Clarify your original question, don't post duplicates.

Comment: and what's the question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than checking length of "," you can also check for text inside span which has ID AddLine2Summary. And if it is empty you can put the code of hiding parent.

It should look like :

```
if ($('#AddLine2Summary').is(':empty')) {
    $("#AddLine2Summary").parent().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try wrapping your HTML snippet in a container to make selection easier:

```
<div class="address-container">
    <p><span id="AddLine1Summary"></span>,</p>
    <p><span id="AddLine2Summary"></span>,</p>
    <p><span id="TownCitySummary"></span>,</p>
    <p><span id="CountySummary"></span>,</p>
    <p><span id="PostcodeSummary"></span></p>
</div>
```

Then in jQuery, look for empty `span` elements in here, and hide their parent `p`.

```
$('.address-container span:empty').closest('p').hide();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bz7eU/)

This will then work for all empty address fields, not just `#AddLine2Summary`.